# How can I list and edit js/css files linked in a master page in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've started to use Visual Studio Code instead of Dreamweaver and one of the things I loved about Dreamweaver is that it listed all the "Related" js/css/php files that were included/linked as href/src values in to the master page for quick editing.

Is there any way I can get this functionality in VSCode? I can't seem to find an extension that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links).

Feel free to add feature requests.